# Unable to start neo4j properly on OSX 10.7.5

Tags: neo4j

I just downloaded neo4j enterprise 1.8.1 and am attempting to start the server and access the web admin.  This is what happens:

```
$ bin/neo4j start
Starting Neo4j Server...16:56:10,175 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
16:56:10,175 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
16:56:10,176 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/Users/sharpei/Downloads/neo4j-enterprise-1.8.1/system/lib/neo4j-server-1.8.1.jar!/logback.xml]
16:56:10,198 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@7786df0f - URL [jar:file:/Users/sharpei/Downloads/neo4j-enterprise-1.8.1/system/lib/neo4j-server-1.8.1.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
16:56:10,262 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
16:56:10,268 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
16:56:10,272 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
16:56:10,288 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
16:56:10,336 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
16:56:10,336 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
16:56:10,338 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.IncludeAction - Could not find resource corresponding to [custom-logback.xml]
16:56:10,339 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@379e8f17 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

process [50657]... waiting for server to be ready...... OK.
Go to http://localhost:7474/webadmin/ for administration interface.
```

I try going to the webadmin url and I just get a blank page. No errors or anything.  I've tried googling the various logs here and I came up with nothing.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any chance you can share that installation? Might there be a permission problem, sinc ehte logback.xml is not recognized as a file? Does the neo4j process have rwx permissions on all files?

Comment: that did it! I just changed the permissions and I got it working! Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify where this file i located?

Comment: How would one give neo4j permission to do this?

Comment: Bump: How do you give neo4j permission?